# Kinect Skeleton change from v1.8 to v2

Tags: c#, kinect

I am currently learning how to use the Microsoft Kinect v1 and its SDKs to find a users height. The code I have written is with C# in VBC. I am using the Skeleton class to find joints and to display the skeleton stream on screen. I recently acquired a new Kinect v2 and the code no longer works. I have converted the joint types perfectly but the class Skeleton no longer exists! Rendering my code completely useless. I am inquiring on what the new Skeleton class is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As it is described [here](http://pterneas.com/2014/03/13/kinect-for-windows-version-2-body-tracking/), the Skeleton class has been replaced by the Body class.
Furthermore [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769608/Understanding-Kinect-Coordinate-Mapping) shows how you can map it on RGB.

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfectly what i was looking for :) +1